# Writing Apex in Spring '14 Prerelease Org

Tags: pre-release

I have the [following question](https://twitter.com/jessealtman/status/425342831478054913):

> As a developer, I want to play w/ the Analytics API in Apex being
>   released Spring '14. Can I get that enabled in a dev org?

I had a long conversation with help from two fellow Twitter users, and I think I finally came to the correct conclusion. **I can't write Apex because it is a Professional Edition.** Is there any way to make this an Enterprise or Unlimited edition so I can write some Apex? Anyone have any idea if I am requesting a prerelease org incorrectly or something? I would assume Salesforce would want to open up their new release to developers to allow any problems with the Apex changes to be found.

Comment: My pre-release orgs was Professional edition as well, which wasn't much use to me either. So whatever we are doing wrong, we are both doing it...I have never seen an option to request a dev org fo pre-release...

Comment: There was apparently a way to do it on prerelease orgs that were requested a few releases ago. Not sure why it changed now. It is pretty annoying because I want to start working w/ some of the new changes.

Comment: Maybe you can ask the Salesforce Salesperson that calls you about your recent interest in Salesforce to upgrade it. ;)

Comment: That isn't a bad idea, although I haven't been contacted by anyone. I considered making a case, but seeing as it is a prerelease org that is not possible.

Comment: Don't forget that you don't necessarily have to sign up for a new pre-release org each release. I've an org on prerelna1 which I've had since May 2012, and it gets upgraded every release. It's often switched off for months at a time, so don't rely on it to save code or data, and don't be surprised if it's deleted at some point, but generally they don't seem to get wiped at each release.

Comment: Thanks @James. That seems to be what everyone else was saying as well. As long as it is available for now before Spring '14 becomes available, that is fine by me.

Comment: for the record, you could just log cases through other orgs (dev or your company's) and have pre-release orgs upgraded. Getting pilots activated is more of a hassle though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can now select between Professional/Developer/Enterprise Edition orgs via the Spring '14 signup form:  https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring14.jsp

[image: Spring 14 Signup]

Answer (score 5):

I went to https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-summer13.jsp which still has the Edition picklist available for sign up.  I selected Ultimate Edition and Partner and it created an Ultimate Edition org for me.  The org that was created was Spring '14.

This is a workaround that will likely go away once you cannot sign up through the summer 13 URL.

[image]

---

**EDIT:** From Pat Patterson ([@metadaddy](https://twitter.com/metadaddy/status/425372550978220032)):

> PE-only this time. #Summer14 will restore pre-rel multiple editions

**UPDATE** You can now select between PE/DE/EE - see my answer (metadaddy)

Comment: Interesting. This may not be something that they want people to use, but it is a workaround for now.

Comment: @JesseAltman - It looks like they close out after a while.  For example "Sorry, the Spring '13 Pre-Release Program is closed" when I go to https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring13.jsp