# How to upgrade developer org?

Tags: update, pre-release, release

How do i upgrade my developer edition org to the latest Salesforce version?  I have a developer org which is winter 14 and i would like to upgrade it to spring 14.  Is there any option in administration to do this?

Comment: You can get a Pre-release org by signing up for a [Spring '14 Prerelease org](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring14.jsp).  If you want to test drive the bleeding edge, it's great. If you really want everything from your existing DE in it, you'd have to copy it in.

Answer (score 7):

Upgrades between releases (API versions) is not something you can do yourself.

Salesforce does this for you and all other production orgs at the same pod at the same time. These moments may vary between servers (pods) and are always announced  per mail to administrators and publicly readable on the trust website.

http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/

Comment: You can spin up a new, pre-release org with Spring 14. See this question for link and details: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25486/3934